# How to read and use ruby-nmap documentation?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, scanning, nmap, port-scanning

I find myself unable to use the ruby-nmap documentation at

> http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-nmap/Nmap

There are simply no code examples and therefore I quite can't figure out on how to use & read the documentation properly. Can somebody give me an overview on how to get started and what for example "#address" means?

Comment: See [how-to-read-ruby-documentation](http://www.rubyletter.com/blog/2017/02/15/how-to-read-ruby-documentation.html). There actually are some custom messages documenting the methods in that rubydoc. `#address` refers to an instance methods, whereas `.address` would be a class method

Comment: you looking this http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-nmap/frames (may be)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have already read the 'how-to-read-ruby-documentation', but it didn't help. I will be trying out to code with the examples given.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the [github page](https://github.com/sophsec/ruby-nmap), that seems to have some usage examples.

Comment: They don't really help. When I copy the code, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```rb
require 'nmap/program'
Nmap::Program.scan(targets: '192.168.0.1', verbose: true)
```

Follow [`Nmap::Program.scan`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-nmap/Nmap%2FProgram%2Escan) documentation and choose your options from [`Nmap::Task`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-nmap/Nmap/Task). Experiment a bit :)